# How to remove child elements from XML using Java?

Tags: java, xml, dom

```
<definitions>
   <form name="enable">
      <data1>...</data1>
      <data2>...</data2>
      <data3>...</data3>
   </form>
   <form>
      <data1>...</data1>
      <data2>...</data2>
      <data3>...</data3>
   </form>
   ...
</definitions>
```

I want to remove the definitions tag child elements(form) those are having the `name` attribute. For eg: in the above case, I want to remove the first `form` element from the document. How to do this in java?

Comment: Are you having the XML as a string only or do you map it internally to some objects? Also, are you using any XML parsing libraries?

Comment: @PetrePopescu Yes, I am having this XML data as a string and I am using the Java `DOM` parser for parsing this XML data.

Comment: Can the name field have different values? @SteveRogers

Comment: Yes @ismlyldz the name attribute has different values. My use case is, I have a string and iterate the form elements one by one. If any one of the `form` name field attribute is matching/equals to the string, I just want to remove that `form` from the `definitions` tag

Comment: Without an XML parsing library, my only solution would be with string manipulation. (using substring, string append, etc). If this is OK for you, I can write a fast prototype in the answer.

Comment: @PetrePopescu using the XML parsing library is ok for me. If you have it or know about it please share. It will be really helpful. If this is not achieved by the parser, please share your string manipulation operation prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that removes all forms that have the `name` attribute:

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class XMLDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        Document document = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("input.xml"));

        XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();

        // Create XPathExpression object
        XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("/definitions/form[@name]");

        // Evaluate expression result on XML document
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        if (nodes.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodes.item(i);
                node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
            }
        }

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        t.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(System.out));
    }
}
```

If you want to remove only forms with `name = "enable"` make this change:

```java
// Create XPathExpression object
XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("/definitions/form[contains(@name, 'enable')]");
```

Comment: thanks for the response. This code works fine and solved the mentioned use case. I have one more doubt is it possible to add another attribute name inside the `compile()`?

Comment: Yes there are many features you can try. You can also browse this link. https://howtodoinjava.com/java/xml/java-xpath-expression-examples/ @SteveRogers